# Member Profile Templates' Language Location?

Tags: templates, language, profile

I can't seem the find the location for the member profile templates' languages.

I'm building a front-end type of control panel for members. It's based off of the default member templates that come with EE, and I am customizing that. What I want to do is change the standard language used for all the member template functions.

For example: {lang:username_and_password} outputs "Username and Password". Or {lang:edit_profile} outputs something like "Edit Your Profile".

I need to change what those language terms render. I've looked inside the control panel found settings that I thought would change this, but only seem to affect the back-end control panel language, not the front-end member profile templates.

Can't find similar questions on here, or topics from EE manuals.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you just have to translate default (English) lang pack and create new lang folder for the translated file versions. And then setup default language for the translated if you don't want English to be default. It's a jungle and takes time but it's worth it if you need it. And of course, if I remember right, someone is even selling language pack at devot:ee...

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/languages.html